# Update Manager fails to check for updates

Tags: software-center, update-manager, updates, re-installation

The Update Manager is giving me a problem. Each time I hit the *Check for updates* button, I get the following error:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/weather-indicator-team/pp/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/weather-indicator-team/pp/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I re-install the Update Manager and then it works properly, the same issue was with the Software Center I did the same and it worked. Any help?

Comment: You have the option of getting an e-mail with answers to your questions once a day. You can scroll down to see this option.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It's never safe to publish your email address on an open web site. I've removed it from the post. If you're sure you want it to be publicly visible, you can [undo this revision](http://askubuntu.com/faq#editing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the PPA location ('pp' instead of 'ppa').

To fix this:

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gksu software-properties-gtk` (press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- After typing in your password, go to the *Other Software* tab and find the two entries that correspond to the error you posted.

  [image]

  [Just an example of how the GUI should look like, I don't have that PPA installed.]
- Select each item, click on the *Edit...* button and fix the typo. The address should be

  ```
  http://ppa.launchpad.net/weather-indicator-team/ppa/ubuntu
  ```

  for both entries.

Close and try the Update Manager again.

Comment: got a window message saying---------Requires installation of untrusted packages

The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources.(weather indicator)

Comment: Open a gnome-terminal and type the following: `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:weather-indicator-team/ppa`. This should take care of authenticating the PPA.

Comment: after entering  got this :--------Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /etc/apt/secring.gpg --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80/ --recv C1995DD92CCEB8E1865DBE2ADFB844B8BB91632D
gpg: requesting key BB91632D from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key BB91632D: public key "Launchpad PPA for Weather Indicator Team" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)

Comment: That sounds okay. Does the Update Manager now work?

Comment: yes it is working :P

Comment: now i get this error says check your internet connection
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon_3.2.0-0ubuntu4_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.40 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntuone-client-gnome/ubuntuone-client-gnome_2.0.0-0ubuntu2_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.40 80]

Comment: That's a different issue and might just be a temporary problem with the servers.